# WebView throws W/Web Console: The page displayed insecure content

Tags: android, https, android-webview

I am trying to load url in my webview, the url is starts with `https://`. The webview is not able to load it and it is throwing error.

```
03-10 18:21:39.280 26988-26988/com.xyz D/WebView: onSizeChanged - w:720 h:1230
03-10 18:21:39.350 26988-26988/com.xyz W/Web Console: The page displayed insecure content!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is purely server side configuration issue. I just verified from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:TLS/SSL_support_history_of_web_browsers) to check whether those TLS and SSL version are enabled or not because Android version below 4.4 uses TLS1.0,1.1